# Is it possible to change Kdialog text color?

Tags: shell, colors, configuration, dialog, kdialog

I have some kdialog textboxes in my script and I need to change its texts colors based on a configuration file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the foreground and background colors for a Kdialog window ([`--fg` and `--bg` options](https://manned.org/kdialog/305d822b)), but it has no way to color individual words on the window.

If you read through the [source-code](https://github.com/KDE/kdialog/tree/master/src), you'll notice that Kdialog is just a [thin layer on top of the KDE widget set](https://github.com/KDE/kdialog/blob/master/src/widgets.cpp#L73), with options corresponding to a [subset of dialog in 2005](https://github.com/KDE/kdialog/blob/master/src/dialog-compat.txt).

Comment: thank you! could you please give me an example of those options? I am trying `kdialog --title "encrypt" --msgbox "$MSG" --background "GREEN"` and it isn't giving me any result. I have tried with --fg as well

Comment: Those are Qt options, and it expects lowercase.  However if you're using it in a "desktop", the color scheme for that will (silently) override the Qt options for color and font...

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it's possible, just use variables in the KDialog parameters to effect the color changes.

KDialogs support styling in a number of ways - in your case the easiest way to change text colour in a KDialog is to use inline HTML styling (KDialog supports basic Qt styling, which is a limited sub-set of CSS).

```
kdialog --title "KDialog" --caption "supports styles" --radiolist "<p style="padding:30"><font style="background:white"><br />&nbsp;Choose a type of <font style="color:red">KDialog</font> from the list&nbsp;</font></p>" 1 'Get user input' Off 2 'Display information' Off 3 'Get user choice' Off --geometry 450x230+200+200)
```

[image: KDialog using inline HTML styles]

KDialogs styling is not well documented (I'm [hoping to change that](https://scottferguson.com.au/community/kdialog.html) - eventually...), but very customizable.

[image: KDialog using system Qt styles, external Qt stylesheet, and inline styling]

```
kdialog  --icon "preferences-system" --stylesheet "radiolist.qss" --title "KDialog" --caption "supports styles" --radiolist "<p style="padding:30"><font style="background:white"><br />&nbsp;Choose a type of <font style="color:red">KDialog</font> from the list&nbsp;</font></p>" 1 'Get user input' Off 2 'Display information' Off 3 'Get user choice' Off --geometry 450x230+200+200
```

Comment: Oh, I've just discovered some new features which aren't in KDialog documentation yet! Meanwhile, "--title" and "--caption" has been merged into "--title" apparently.

Comment: You can edit the original response in such cases :)